# Making an AJAX request with AngularJS

Tags: sql, angularjs, click

i started an Angularjs app just to learn more about the js framework, i'm confused in some things like working with sql so i want a little help to make a show on click table.

What im trying to do is make a request to the database and fill a table with `ng-repeat`, then show with a sliding effect when i click a button.

I dont have any idea how to get the sql query and insert into a controller in angularjs, please help.

Database movies table:

```
|--id--|------text------|-----year-----|
|______________________________________|
|--1---|----avengers----|-----2012-----|
|--2---|------mama------|-----2013-----|
```

I want to pass it to angularjs like:

```
$scope.movies = [
{text:'Mama', year:'2013',id:2},
{text:'Avengers', year:'2012',id:1}];
```

Answer (score 1):

This should help you get started.  It's a simple controller with data-binding to a property named `myScopeData`.  The code uses the `$http` object in Angular to make an AJAX request to your PHP to retrieve data from your database.  The scope variable `myScopeData` gets set and updates the view.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="mainController">
        {{myScopeData}}        
    </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('mainController',function($scope,$http){
    $http({method:'GET',url:'movies.php'}).success(function(data){
        $scope.myScopeData = data;
    });  
});
```